# Swiper - OpenCart - background full size image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I am trying to make background full size image for every single slide in slideshow in OpenCart. As I see, OpenCart uses Swiper to create this slider. Here is how my `html` looks like:

```
{% for banner in banners %}
    <div class="swiper-slide text-center" style="background: url({{ banner.image }}); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: cover;">
        ...
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As I assume, `background-size: cover` should cover whole background. But despite this the result is next:

[image]

Looks like background image is trying to fit in block only by top and bottom corners. Is there is anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, but the CSS property is actually "`background-attachment: cover;`" rather than "`background-size: cover;`".
This should fix the issue you're calling.
Another thing that might help is using the shorthand method for background, for example, instead of using `background: url({{ banner.image }}); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: cover;`
You can use `background: #000000 url({{banner.image}}) no-repeat cover center;`